# If Dynamo table has both PK and SK, would it possible to query table find all records that have a PK that begins with "abc" without specifying the SK

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I did some research, but it seems like if the table has both PK and SK, i need to specify both on them in the query ?

I am using QueryRequest in JAVA

```
    Map<String, String> expressionAttributeNames = new HashMap<>();
    expressionAttributeNames.put("#pk", "pk");
    Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
    expressionAttributeValues.put(":pk", new AttributeValue().withS("abc"));

    QueryRequest queryRequest =
                            new QueryRequest()
                                .withTableName(tableName)
                                .withKeyConditionExpression("#pk begins_with :pk")
                               .withExpressionAttributeNames(expressionAttributeNames).withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues);
```

This give me an error like
"Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: "begins_with", near: "#d begins_with :d" (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: B9PO9PC8LETMIADFPM3RBOG32FVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null"

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full PK value when doing a Query.

There’s probably a way to solve your issue, if you can get the value as a sort key on the items such as with a GSI.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, Can i use scan ?  i mean to scan the table to find all records that have a PK that begins with "abc" without specifying the SK?

Comment: Scan is always an option for every read use case, but it requires reading the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't do a begins_with, you can pull the entire PartitionKey an dthen filter that. Set up the parameters to just define the `KeyConditionValue` with just a  Partition Key specified. (The below assumes your Partition Key is named `PK`):

```
let params = {  
            TableName: YOUR_TABLE_NAME,
            KeyConditionExpression: `PK=:foo`,
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":foo": YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE,
            }
        }
```

You can pass the following params to `dynamoClient.query(params)`.  Here  is an example of how you might do that:

```
try {
    const myItems = []
    let data
    do {
        data = await dynamoClient.query(params).promise()
        data.Items.forEach((user) => {
            myItems.push(user)
        })
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey
    } while (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey !== "undefined")
    return myItems
} catch (err) {
    callback(new Error(`[500] ${err.message}`))
}
```